# how to create store procedure for this mysql query which i want to call from php

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT *
 FROM employee
 INNER JOIN experience ON employee.PersonID=experience.PersonID WHERE employee.Firstname LIKE '%".$fname."%' AND experience.Year_Of_Experience >= $year;
```

As I am using inner join of two table and can any one help with how to call from php to fetch the data from database.

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing based on your params that this would be suitable:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS great_procedure_name $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `great_procedure_name`(fname varchar(21844) CHARACTER SET utf8, year int)

BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM employee
INNER JOIN experience 
ON employee.PersonID = experience.PersonID 
WHERE employee.Firstname LIKE CONCAT('%', fname , '%') 
AND experience.Year_Of_Experience >= year;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then to call it:

```
CALL great_procedure_name('abc', 23);
```

I tested this out on my system before posting the answer, so it should work for you. I don't know how you are doing MySQL queries in your PHP, but using CALL is usually quite straight forward. The problem many people will have is that procedures can return multiple results, so you need to be prepared to step through them, even when all you have is one.

Answer (score 1):

her is a very good example for php and database:

> Now that we have our sample SQL query, we can use it to create the php
>   code that will print all comments on a page. Below is the example code
>   that we created. If you're not familiar with php, any line that begins
>   with a // is a comment, and comments are used by developers to
>   document their code. In our example, we have quite a few comments to
>   help explain what the code is doing, but keep in mind that most
>   scripts do not have as many comments.

```
<?

// At this point in the code, we want to show all of the comments
// submitted by users for this particular page. As the comments
// are stored in the database, we will begin by connecting to
// the database

// Below we are setting up our connection to the server. Because
// the database lives on the same physical server as our php code,
// we are connecting to "localhost". inmoti6_myuser and mypassword
// are the username and password we setup for our database when
// using the "MySQL Database Wizard" within cPanel

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","inmoti6_myuser","mypassword");

// The statement above has just tried to connect to the database.
// If the connection failed for any reason (such as wrong username
// and or password, we will print the error below and stop execution
// of the rest of this php script

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// We now need to select the particular database that we are working with
// In this example, we setup (using the MySQL Database Wizard in cPanel) a
// database named inmoti6_mysite

mysql_select_db("inmoti6_mysite", $con);

// We now need to setup our SQL query to grab all comments from this page.
// The example SQL query we copied from phpMyAdmin is:
// SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =1 LIMIT 0 , 30
// If we run this query, it will ALWAYS grab only the comments from our
// article with an id of 1. We therefore need to update the SQL query
// so that on article 2 is searches for the "2", on page is searches for
// "3", and so on.
// If you notice in the URL, the id of the article is set after id=
// For example, in the following URL:
// http://phpandmysql.inmotiontesting.com/page2.php?id=2
// ... the article id is 2. We can grab and store this number in a variable
// by using the following code:

$article_id = $_GET['id'];

// We also want to add a bit of security here. We assume that the $article_id
// is a number, but if someone changes the URL, as in this manner:
// http://phpandmysql.inmotiontesting.com/page2.php?id=malicious_code_goes_here
// ... then they will have the potential to run any code they want in your
// database. The following code will check to ensure that $article_id is a number.
// If it is not a number (IE someone is trying to hack your website), it will tell
// the script to stop executing the page

if( ! is_numeric($article_id) )
  die('invalid article id');

// Now that we have our article id, we need to update our SQL query. This
// is what it looks like after we update the article number and assign the
// query to a variable named $query

$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =$article_id LIMIT 0 , 30";

// Now that we have our Query, we will run the query against the database
// and actually grab all of our comments

$comments = mysql_query($query);

// Before we start writing all of the comments to the screen, let's first
// print a message to the screen telling our users we're going to start
// printing comments to the page.

echo "<h1>User Comments</h1>";

// We are now ready to print our comments! Below we will loop through our
// comments and print them one by one.

// The while statement will begin the "looping"

/*NOTE that in PHP 7.0, the mysql_fetch_array has been removed -it was previously deprecated 
in earlier versions of PHP.  You find the cod documentation here:  
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php */

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

  // As we loop through each comment, the specific comment we're working
  // with right now is stored in the $row variable.

  // for example, to print the commenter's name, we would use:
  // $row['name']

  // if we want to print the user's comment, we would use:
  // $row['comment']

  // As this is a beginner tutorial, to make our code easier to read
  // we will take the values above (from our array) and put them into
  // individual variables

  $name = $row['name'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $website = $row['website'];
  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];

  // Be sure to take security precautions! Even though we asked the user
  // for their "name", they could have typed anything. A hacker could have
  // entered the following (or some variation) as their name:
  //
  // <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://SomeBadWebsite.com";</script>
  //
  // If instead of printing their name, "John Smith", we would be printing
  // javascript code that redirects users to a malicious website! To prevent
  // this from happening, we can use the htmlspecialchars function to convert
  // special characters to their HTML entities. In the above example, it would
  // instead print:
  //
  // <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://SomeBadWebsite.com";</script>
  //
  // This certainly would look strange on the page, but it would not be harmful
  // to visitors

  $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $website = htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);

  // We will now print the comment to the screen

  echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
      Name: $name<br />
      Email: $email<br />
      Website: $website<br />
      Comment: $comment<br />
      Timestamp: $timestamp
    </div>
  ";
}

// At this point, we've added the user's comment to the database, and we can
// now close our connection to the database:
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

*check the site -*  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-php-and-mysql/grab-all-comments-from-database